# How to calculate equivalence relations

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

How can I calculate how many equivalence relations can be defined on a given set?  For example:

> How many possible equivalence relations can be defined on S =
>   {a,b,c,d}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so equivalence relations effectively partition $S$ into subsets where each element in a given subset is related to each other element in that subset.  This means you simply need to count all the ways you can partition four elements.

Comment: Is the answer 15?

Comment: Yes, it is (as Adi Dani's answer indicates).

Answer (score 2):

Number of partitions of set is called Bell number and that number satissfy followin recurrence $$B_0=1,B_{n+1}=\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}B_k$$ in your case $n=4$.