# list all the equivalence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

list all the equivanlance relations in the set A={1,2,3,4)

so there should be 15 right?
so what I got so far 
(1 1) (22) (33) (44)
(12) (13) (14)
(21) (23) (24)
(31) (32) (34)
(41) (42) (43)
these are 16 what did i do wrong

Comment: You're right, there are 15.  None of the things you listed are equivalence relations.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to calculate equivalence relations](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/575301/how-to-calculate-equivalence-relations) or [How many equivalence relations on a set with 4 elements](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/676519/how-many-equivalence-relations-on-a-set-with-4-elements)

Comment: The search [how many equivalence relations](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=+how+many+equivalence+relations) finds many related questions, including people asking how to enumerate the equivalence relations on a set with 3 elements and a set with 5 elements.

Answer (score 0):

Since equivalence relations must be reflexive, symmetric, and transitive we must apply this definition to set A. It might be a good idea to think of directed graphs when listing out the equivalence relations.
To start with, {(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4)},{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4),(1,2),(2,1)},...
I am sure you can continue from there.

Comment: That is a clumsy way to write an equivalence relation.  An equivalence relation on $\{1,2,3,4\}$ induces a partition on the set $\{1,2,3,4\}$, and it is much easier to list the partitions than to list the relations as sets of ordered pairs.

Comment: True but judging by his answer I went with the safe route without introducing equiv classes and partitions, which may have been something he has yet to cover in his class.